# Cannot read image from JSON file

Tags: jquery, html, json, angularjs

I want to read the image from JSON file and then it returns nothing with undefined I'm not sure what I am missing. I am very new to this. I'm using AngularJS. I try to use console.log to check variable but it seems like variables cannot catch the value.

**HTML**

```
         <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
           <div class="banner">
            <ul id="lightSlider" >
             <li ng-repeat="image in images"><img ng-src="{{image.img}}"> 
             </li>
            </ul>
           </div>
         </body>
```

**JS**

```
          var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
          app.controller('myCtrl',["$scope","$http", "$timeout" 
          ,function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
            $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: 'imageSlider.json'
              }).then(function successCallback(data){
              $scope.images = data.items;
              console.log(data.items);
            }, function errorCallback(response){
              alert("something went wrong!")
            });
                    $timeout(function(){
                    $("#lightSlider").lightSlider({
                      item:1,
                      auto: true,
                      loop:true,
                      speed:1000,
                      pause:3000,

                });
                  },0)
             }]);
```

Comment: So what does `data.items` look like? Also you need to initalize the plugin inside the success callback and allow some time for the images to load also

Comment: It's come from my JSON file.
{
  "items" : [
    {
      "img": "s2.jpg",
      "alt" : "Image 1"
    },
    {
      "img": "ss1.jpg",
      "alt" : "Image 2"
    },
    {
      "img": "sss3.jpg",
      "alt" : "Image 3"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: How to initialize the plugin?

Comment: I haven't done AngularJS in years but you probably need `data.data.items` since the `$http.get()` promise resolves with the `response`, not the data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined $http data when resolved with \`.then\` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766361/undefined-http-data-when-resolved-with-then-method)

Comment: It's working now thank man I appreciate your help.